# Eclipse RCP: How to add my view to a context

Tags: eclipse-rcp

My question: How do I add my View to an Eclipse Context.

I have created a View for Eclipse and I would like to add the keybinding M1+F to it, since my view will have its own search-mechanism. In the Manifest I added the command and the keybinding with the help of:

```
org.eclipse.ui.commands
org.eclipse.ui.bindings
```

However, I'm having trouble with the eclipse Context. I would like to bind this key only to my view so that it won't clash with Eclipse's default Search mechanism for the editor. To do this I created my own context (org.eclipse.ui.contexts) and put my keybinding to that context.

However, how do I add my view to this context? So that the keybinding will only work for my view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `createPartControl` for the view part activate the context:

```java
IContextService contextService = (IContextService)getSite().getService(IContextService.class);

contextService.activateContext("context id");
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something in the Manifest but this does the trick perfectly.

Comment: Not works for me [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970214/adding-context-to-my-view-and-binding-key-to-this-context)