# Adding context to my view and binding key to this context

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

My question is same as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950537/eclipse-rcp-how-to-add-my-view-to-a-context). But the solution provided there not works for me.

I have activated the context as said in the answer by **greg-449** in `createPartControl` of my view.

```
IContextService contextService =  IContextService)getSite().getService(IContextService.class);        
        contextService.activateContext(myViewContextId);
```

When my view was activated I am getting below warning on eclipse console

> !MESSAGE A conflict occurred for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>:
>
> Binding(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,
>       ParameterizedCommand(Command(**myFindCmdId**,Find,
>           ,
>           Category(org.eclipse.core.commands.categories.autogenerated,Uncategorized,Commands that were either auto-generated or have no category,true),
>           org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@f41266e,
>           ,,true),null),
>       org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
>       **myViewContextId**,,,system)
>
> Binding(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,
>       ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.edit.findReplace,Find and Replace,
>           Find and replace text,
>           Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.edit,Edit,null,true),
>           org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@24ad92b0,
>           ,,true),null),
>       org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
>       org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

===Plugin.xml has ====

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.contexts">
  <context
        id=<myViewContextId>
        name="abc">
  </context>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <key
        commandId=<myFindCmdId>
        contextId=<myViewContextId>
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        sequence="M1+F">
  </key> 
  //some more key binding here
</extension>
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the conflict message define you own key binding scheme using the `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` extension point and specify the standard `org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration` as the parent id for the scheme. Put your key bindings in this new scheme.

Use:

```
org.eclipse.ui/KEY_CONFIGURATION_ID=schemeid
```

in your `plugin_customization.ini` to select your scheme as the default.

More [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FwrkAdv_keyBindings.htm)

Note: If your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is a Find command you should hook in to the existing Eclipse find/replace retargetable action rather than defining new commands and key bindings.

So for Find do not define any command, handler or key bindings. Instead in your ViewPart use

```java
IActionBars bars = getViewSite().getActionBars();

bars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.FIND.getId(), your find Action);
```

Comment: Its working partially what I want is when my view was active and user pressed **Ctrl + F** then my command should execute also when my view was in-active then it should open eclipse `Find and Replace` dialog. Do I need to use scheme for this?Or is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Added Eclipse IDE plugin way to use find

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **parentId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"** into your new context:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.contexts">
  <context
        id=<myViewContextId>
        name="abc">
        parentId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window">
  </context>
</extension>
```